# Cauchy sequence of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I know (from calculus) the Cauchy convergence theorem for sequence of real numbers...how to show it with random variables?

I have $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i;$  $X_i$ being iid centered r.v., $S_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2$, I have to show it converges to $S$ ($E((S_n-S)^2)=0$)

I have to show also that $E(\sum_i^\infty X_i^2)<\infty$ (this should be easy) and that $X_n\rightarrow 0 (a.s.)$ (here I need help)

Answer (score 1):

Because $E(\sum_i^\infty X_i^2)<\infty$, so $\sum_i^\infty X_i^2<+\infty, a.s$. So $X_i^2\rightarrow 0, a.s$ as well as $X_i$.

Comment: ok...and about the convergence of $S_n$ to $S$ in quadratic mean?

Comment: You have shown that $E(\sum_n^\infty X_n^2)=\sum_n^\infty E(X_n^2)<\infty$, so $E(S_n-S)^2=E(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty X_k^2) =\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty E(X_k^2)\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow 0$ because they are the remained terms.

Comment: ok, but I didn't show that, if $S_n$ is a cauchy sequence in $L^2$, it converges in quadratic mean (that's my main problem)

Comment: $L^2$ is Banach space, so any cauchy sequence of r.v's in $L^2$ converges to a certain r.v which is also in $L^2$. So $S_n \rightarrow S $ in $L^2$.

Comment: is that a definition? I remember from my calculus studies there was a theorem (at least for real numbers).

Comment: It is a theorem in analysis, if you don't familiar with it, just use $E(S-S_n)^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty E(X_k^2)\rightarrow 0$, we directly got $S_n$ converges to $S$ in quadratic mean.